# c++ segmentation fault in "empty" main (in a non-empty project)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

I have been developping an application with a colleague, after pulling the last version from CVS, it stopped working... in a funny way.

It started producing a segmentation fault (yep, nothing funny or curious about this).

I am looking for who is causing the segmentation fault. My problem is that I seem to have narrowed it down to... no-one .

At this moment, the main looks like this:

```
//lots of commented includes
int main(int argc,  char** argv)
{
      // some commented code
      exit(0);
}
```

So at this moment I basically have:

- A pretty long cmakelist.txt with quite a few classes, external libraries...
- A makefile generated with cmake that allows me to compile everything without complains.
- An empty main function (at this moment at least) with no includes.

But when I run the code *I still get a segmentation fault*. So the code compiles and links without complain but it produces a segmentation fault when it runs.

When I try to debug the code using the debugger built into Clion (I am pretty sure it is GDB) it starts, outputs a sigsev message and *then* keeps running until it outputs exit(0) (even if I change the exit(0) in the code to exit(1) it still just outputs exit(0) ).

I have some years of experience debugging c++ code but in this case I do not know how to go on, I understand I am not giving enough details to get a speciffic answer but any ideas would be much appreciated.

Some more details:

- I have checked that I can still compile and run a hello world example with CLION, so no major configuration problems, I can even compile and run the previous version of the code.
- Differences between the two versions are substantial, but include no new external libraries, only some new classes developed by ourselves.
- I have been researching this and it looks like static creator functions from included classes might be a problem but as I have no includes I believe I should be safe, am I right?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This can also be in other cpp files or libraries which get compiled/linked into the program. Not only include files. So if you have some global/static variables there this can also cause this. A debugger would point you to what causes the fault.

Comment: So gdb outputs the sigsegv message and keeps executing? That's odd. Does gdb behave as it should in other programs? (Try `int main() { *(int*)nullptr; }` or something like that.)

Comment: How is your question related to CMake or CLion? Please remove those tags.

Comment: you can use the tool Valgrind to investigate a segfault, then you will get the actual line number

Comment: So I asked Valgrind and here is what the output looks like:

Bad permissions for mapped region at address...
boost::math::lanczos::lanczos_initializer<boost::math::lanczos::lanczos17m64, long double>::init::init() (in /usr/lib/libpcl_sample_consensus.so.1.7.2)
by 0xA64A6BD: ??? (in /usr/lib/libpcl_sample_consensus.so.1.7.2)
by 0x4010109: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:78)
by 0x40101F2: call_init (dl-init.c:36)
by 0x40101F2: _dl_init (dl-init.c:126)

I guess it is some problem between PCL and boost, I will check this now.

Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @ydiez For future, when you have additional details, especially code or program output snippets, please edit the question and add it there, not in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I managed to solve the issue I am posting some details here in case it helps someone.

I am using the Point Cloud library that uses boost. I tried reinstalling both of them without any success. Then I decided to change the version of PCL hoping that this would do the trick.

I used [this link](https://larrylisky.com/2014/03/03/installing-pcl-on-ubuntu/) to download, compile an install a version of PCL different of that provided with my ubuntu system. This solved the problem. However, it looks like the problem was not in the library itself but in some of its dependencies.

Specifically, I run into trouble when trying to install the libflann1 package.

I solved that by installing instead libflann-dev.

After doing this, I went back to [the ubuntu provided version of the library](http://pointclouds.org/downloads/linux.html) (currently 1.7.0) and everything worked like a charm.

I am still not sure why the application failed at this particular moment, I guess the code started using some function that affected the part that was not properly installed.

All in all, I learned that linked libraries (even if they are not included) can produce run-time segmentation faults when they initialize, I got the hint of what the offending library was from valgrind (thanks Dac Saunders!) and managed to fix a faulty installation.

Now it's back to programming, thanks for your help.

Comment: C++ libraries may contain static objects with constructors that are executed during program startup